# What was Bobby Fischer's actual chess strength during the 1992 re-match vs. Spassky?

Tags: fischer, spassky

As title above, what was Bobby Fischer's actual chess strength during the 1992 re-match vs. Spassky, apart from all his already legendary past achievements?

Comment: About 2650 stated in Kasparov's book. I remember Kasparov about it in his book.

Answer (score 12):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer%E2%80%93Spassky_(1992_match)):

> Fischer's score of 17½ out of 30 (counting draws) against Spassky, rated 2545 at the time, gave him a performance rating of 2645, which would have put him at No. 12 in the world on the July 1992 list.